# How to extract data from "youtube-mp3.org" API response?

Tags: php

Before I say anything, a SAMP scripter has managed to do this in pawn.

Here is his code.
http://pastebin.com/RMVWdtzj

When you type this url as shown without the `h` variable listed, you get redirected to the homepage.

```
youtube-mp3.org/get?video_id=O-fyNgHdmLI
```

If you type the url with the `h` variable listed, `youtube-mp3.org/get?video_id=O-fyNgHdmLI&h=44348f6e92d82b85311aaf3d702d9080&r=1365043075897`, a download starts automatically.

Therefore I'm needing to grab the variable called `h` that is returned from this file so that I can incorporate it into my urls and the download will start automatically.

Here's what I have.

```
$u2burl = file_get_contents("http://www.youtube-mp3.org/api/itemInfo/?video_id=$ytsong");
```

For example if `$ytsong = O-fyNgHdmLI`

Then `$u2burl` will return

```
info = { "title" : "Creed - My Sacrifice (Video)", "image" : "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/O-fyNgHdmLI/default.jpg", "length" : "4", "status" : "serving", "progress_speed" : "", "progress" : "", "ads" : "", "pf" : "", "h" : "44348f6e92d82b85311aaf3d702d9080" };
```

I need to put just the last part `(44348f6e92d82b85311aaf3d702d9080)` in a variable.

ex: `$hval = 44348f6e92d82b85311aaf3d702d9080`

But how do I get the script to do this automatically?

I can't set the variable by myself each time, therefore I need to know how to get the script to take the data listed from `file_get_contents` and grab just the last part `(44348f6e92d82b85311aaf3d702d9080)` and throw it in a variable for me.

It seems that the `h` changes with each user's IP address...
It's a long shot, but is it possible?

Comment: This is just something I want to learn how to do.

Comment: Try with Quick MP3 API v1 http://www.quick-mp3.com/api/v1/docs/

Answer (score 0):

Strip the `info =` prefix and `;` suffix and use `json_decode` to decode the string into an associative array. Then just index it as you would a normal associative array for the key `"h"`.